# CSS - How to deactivate the :hover pseudo class in IE 6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, hover, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I use a hover navigation and it all works well. I'm really satisfied. But I'm also sadistic to the IE6 - so is there a CSS way to deactivate the :hover pseudo class?

like

```html
...
<!--[if IE 6]>
<style>
#topNavigation #top_right li.directlinks:hover ul {dont-let-me-do-that:true;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<bod....>
```

But I think there is not such a function.. so maybe a JQuery snippet? Well I count on you guys!

**Edit:**
Here my actual code - and yes ... it does work on a li. I CAN hover it in IE6 (but its a bit buggy so I will disable this function and I work with a JQUERY hover(function()...)

```
#topNavigation #top_right li.directlinks:hover ul {display:block}
```

Comment: If you happen to be using [`Whatever:hover`](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html), that will be fixing IE6 for you. Be sure to remove it.

Comment: Re edit: proof of concept or it didn't happen :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE6 doesn't support `:hover` on anything but `a` elements anyway, so it's got you covered there.

That said, if you'd like to hide any rules from IE6, it's just a matter of tossing in the child combinator somewhere in the selector, here's the famous `html > body` hack:

```
html > body #topNavigation #top_right li.directlinks:hover ul
```

But I **seriously doubt** your selector works on anything but a patched IE6 MSHTML.